# Content not staying in their divs on resize

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes with backgrounds that change color on mouseover. Above their backgrounds are placeholder images for now. I'm using vw for the backgrounds so that when the window is resized they change size to match.

I'm trying to get the images to align to the center of the box and to resize according to their boxes.

Here's my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DPMC87/84e6fgzy/)

```
<div class="socialbox">
    <ul class="socialNavList">
        <li class="navlinkedin"><a href="#">linkedin</a></li>
        <li class="navtwitter"><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
        <li class="navfacebook"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding image as background to anchor tags like this:

```
ul.socialNavList li.navfacebook a {
    background: #ccc url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-32-32-1.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 85% 85%;        
}
```

This way you have responsive background.
Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/84e6fgzy/1/) to try it.

Notice I added just for the third item, to show you the effect.

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately when I did, the image doesn't show.

Comment: did you see the fiddle?

Comment: I did, thank you so much! I see what I did wrong. I had a:hover on the two that didn't work. Perfect! Thanks very much! Can't accept answer just yet but will when it let's me :)

Comment: I will do when it let's me :) Just noticed one thing. I want there to be a background color before hovering too. The image needs to sit above the background if you get me?

Comment: in that case, lower the percentages, cause 100% cover the whole space

Comment: I did but there's no background fill color now only on hover?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! Can I ask you why applying vertical-align:middle; to the image doesn't center it inside the box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91639/discussion-between-1l13v-and-dpmc87).